# Unix shell scripting, need to adjust my script for performance?

Tags: bash, shell, ksh, rsync, aix

I have a script below that does a few things...

```
#!/bin/bash

# Script to sync dr-xxxx
# 1. Check for locks and die if exists
# 2. CPIO directories found in cpio.cfg
# 3. RSYNC to remote server
# 5. TRAP and remove lock so we can run again

if ! mkdir /tmp/drsync.lock; then
        printf "Failed to aquire lock.\n" >&2
        exit 1
fi
trap 'rm -rf /tmp/drsync.lock' EXIT  # remove the lockdir on exit

# Config specific to CPIO
BASE=/home/mirxx
DUMP_DIR=/usrx/drsync
CPIO_CFG="$BASE/cpio.cfg"

while LINE=: read -r f1 f2
do
  echo "Working with $f1"
  cd $f1
  find . -print | cpio -o | gzip > $DUMP_DIR/$f2.cpio.gz
  echo "Done for $f1"
done <"$CPIO_CFG"

RSYNC=/usr/bin/rsync # use latest version
RSYNC_BW="4500" # 4.5MB/sec
DR_PATH=/usrx/drsync
DR_USER=root
DR_HOST=dr-xxxx
I=0
MAX_RESTARTS=5 # max rsync retries before quitting
LAST_EXIT_CODE=1

while [ $I -le $MAX_RESTARTS ]
do
  I=$(( $I + 1 ))
  echo $I. start of rsync
  $RSYNC \
           --partial \
           --progress \
           --bwlimit=$RSYNC_BW \
           -avh $DUMP_DIR/*gz \
               $DR_USER@$DR_HOST:$DR_PATH
  LAST_EXIT_CODE=$?
  if [ $LAST_EXIT_CODE -eq 0 ]; then
        break
  fi
done

# check if successful
if [ $LAST_EXIT_CODE -ne 0 ]; then
  echo rsync failed for $I times. giving up.
else
  echo rsync successful after $I times.
fi
```

What I would like to change above is, for this line..

```
  find . -print | cpio -o | gzip > $DUMP_DIR/$f2.cpio.gz
```

I am looking to change the above line so that it starts a parallel process for every entry in CPIO_CFG which gets feed in. I believe i have to use & at the end? Should I implement any safety precautions?

Is it also possible to modify the above command to also include an exclude list that I can pass in via $f3 in the cpio.cfg file.

For the below code..

```
while [ $I -le $MAX_RESTARTS ]
do
  I=$(( $I + 1 ))
  echo $I. start of rsync
  $RSYNC --partial --progress --bwlimit=$RSYNC_BW -avh $DUMP_DIR/*gz $DR_USER@$DR_HOST:$DR_PATH
  LAST_EXIT_CODE=$?
  if [ $LAST_EXIT_CODE -eq 0 ]; then
        break
  fi
done
```

The same thing here, is it possible to run multiple RSYNC threads one for .gz file found in $DUMP_DIR/*.gz

I think the above would greatly increase the speed of my script, the box is fairly beefy (AIX 7.1, 48 cores and 192GB RAM).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Execute the find in a subshell which you send to the background e.g. `(cd $f1 && find . -print | cpio -o | gzip > $DUMP_DIR/$f2.cpio.gz &)`

Comment: this seems to be going in the right direction, how can I make it so I wait until all the CPIO finish before continuing on with the script to do the rsync.

Comment: `help wait` `wait`, well, waits for all subprocesses to finish

Answer (score 1):

The original code is a traditional batch queue. Let's add a bit of lean thinking...

The actual workflow is the transformation and transfer of a set of directories in compressed cpio format.  Assuming that there is no dependency between the directories/archives, we should be able to create a single action for creating the archive and the transfer.

It helps if we break up the script into functions, which should make our intentions more visible.

First, create a function `transfer_archive()` with `archive_name` and an optional `number_of_attempts` as arguments.  This contains your second `while` loop, but replaces `$DUMP_DIR/*gz` with `$archive_name`.  Details will be left as an exercise.

```
 function transfer_archive {
     typeset archive_name=${1:?"pathname to archive expected"} 
     typeset number_of_attempts=${2:-1}

     (
         n=0
         while 
             ((n++))
             ((n<=number_of_attempts))
         do
             ${RSYNC:?} 
                 --partial \
                 --progress \
                 --bwlimit=${RSYNC_BW:?} \
                 -avh ${archive_name:?} ${DR_USER:?}@${DR_HOST:?}:${DR_PATH:?} && exit 0
         done
         exit 1
     )
 }
```

Inside the function we use a subshell, `(` ... `)` with two exit statements.
The function will return the exit value of the subshell, either true (rsync succeeded), or false (too many attempts).

We then combine that with archive creation:

```
function create_and_transfer_archive {
    (
        # only cd in a subshell - no confusion upstairs
        cd ${DUMP_DIR:?Missing global setting} || exit

        dir=${1:?directory}
        archive=${2:?archive}

        # cd, find and cpio must be in the same subshell together
        (cd ${dir:?} && find . -print | cpio -o ) |
             gzip > ${archive:?}.cpio.gz || return # bail out 

        transfer_archive ${archive:?}.cpio.gz
    )
 }
```

Finally, your main loop will process all directories in parallel:

```
while LINE=: read -r dir archive_base
do
    (
        create_and_transfer_archive $dir ${archive_base:?} &&
            echo $dir Done || echo $dir failed            
    ) &
done <"$CPIO_CFG" | cat
```

Instead of the pipe with `cat`, you could just add `wait` at the end of the script, but
it has the nice effect of capturing all output from the background processes.

Now, I've glossed over one important aspect, and that is the number of jobs you can run in
parallel.  This will scale reasonably well, but it would be better to actually maintain a
job queue.  Above a certain number, adding more jobs will start to slow things down, and 
at that point you will have to add a job counter and a job limit.  Once the job limit is
reached, stop starting more `create_and_transfer_archive` jobs, until processes have completed.

How to keep track of those jobs is a separate question.

Comment: The code had grown way past an exercise, I'd better add some tests. Removed some serious errors in the logic.